# How to use transition-timing-function: ease to create ease-in transitions

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

For a digital comic strip that I want to develop, I wonder if it's possible to create ease-ins or ease-outs with **transition-timing-function: ease**.

I inserted transition-timing-function in an old "animation" but it seems to have no effect, even changing the parameters wildly. I'm probably doing something stupid. Mixing pears with apples or putting eggs in tomato cans.

Can someone guide me on this?

The piece of CSS code is:

```
.rotate {
  animation: 1s linear infinite rotate;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: 103% 98%;
  transform-delay: 2s;
   /* THIS IS NEW */
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  /* THIS IS NEW */ 
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.25, 1);
}
```

The Codepen:
https://codepen.io/Sergio_Urra/pen/JVEexy

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format.

Comment: From what I could understand, you can specify the animation-timing-function itself instead of `1s linear` use `1s ease-in`. There is no need of any transition in your code.

Comment: @Servesh Chaturvedi. You're right. I realized when I looked more calmly and attentively. A little accumulated stress made me lose attention to details. Thanks.